# Can't Play RTSP Stream (3gp encode) on Android 2.2

Tags: android, stream, rtsp

I tried to play a RTSP stream "rtsp://217.146.95.166:554/playlist/ch27yqcif.3gp" (this stream tested on KM Player and it is alive)
and also tried to play from "m.youtube.com" but not success. It give me an error "Sorry this video cannot be played" when the program run.

here is my code.

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoView);
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
 mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
 Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://217.146.95.166:554/playlist/ch27yqcif.3gp");


                 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                 videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                 videoView.start();
```

The app run and download data for sometime and give me the error "Sorry this video cannot be played"

when I try this http link it play well.
http://3gpvideos.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/13/Ishq%20Mein%20Ruswaa%20Full%20Song.3gp

I tried so many different RTSP links and formats but not successful.
What is the wrong with this code.

log details..

```
05-16 08:52:38.633: D/MediaPlayer(275): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-16 08:53:52.272: W/MediaPlayer(275): info/warning (1, 26)
05-16 08:53:52.272: I/MediaPlayer(275): Info (1,26)
05-16 08:53:52.313: E/MediaPlayer(275): error (1, -1)
05-16 08:53:52.313: E/MediaPlayer(275): Error (1,-1)
05-16 08:53:52.313: D/VideoView(275): Error: 1,-1
```